# alignment problem for td contents

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html>

.................
....
.......

 <td colspan="4" ><br>&lt;40      : Negative<br>40-80    : positieve <br></td>
```

it results in the following HTML

```
40:Negative
40-80:Positive
```

what I would need is

```
40   :Negative
40-80:Positive
```

is it possible to use css to make this happen? or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `<pre>`

```
    <td colspan="4" >
      <pre>
&lt;40    : Negative
40-80  : positieve
      </pre>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well if you're not opposed to using tables (and it looks like you're not :) ), then just stick that in a table too:

```
<td>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>&lt;40</td> <td>:Negative</td></tr>
      <tr><td>40-80</td> <td>:Positive</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your spaces with Non-breaking space characters,

```
<td colspan="4" ><br>&lt;40&nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;: Negative<br>40-80nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;: positieve <br></td>
```

Comment: thanks, but this content comes from dynamic sources. So cannot predict the number of &nbsp ; :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using line breaks (`<br>`) instead of a new `<td>` row.  Without looking at the rest of your layout, it is impossible to align these without using spaces (`&nbsp;`) using just one row, or without further splitting the data into 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your numbers in span and give it some width.

and why do you have this `<br>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/hwGrj/ )

```
<table>
    <td>
        <span class='item'>
            <span class='num'>40</span>
            <span class='posneg'>:Negative</span>
        </span>
        <span class='item'>
            <span class='num'>40-80</span>
            <span class='posneg'>:Positive</span>
        </span>
    </td>
</table>

span.item{
 display: block;
}
span.num{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40px;  
}
```

This solutions uses CSS for the layout with in your table. You will need to wrap your elements in a couple of spans.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre>` tag which display the text in a fixed-width font and preserves both spaces and line breaks

`<td><pre>40   :Negative</pre></td>`

The default styles can be overriden using CSS however.